# Establish more secure symmetric crypto system given A and B have small initial secret

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman, symmetric

Alice and Bob have a secret number *X* that is known only to them. However, the number is only 14 bits, and Trudy knows they share such a secret and can intercept messages between them. Instead of using *X* right of the bat for their symmetric key, Alice and Bob want a more secure system because Trudy can brute force *X*. How can Alice and Bob have establish a more secure system?

My textbook points at Diffe-Hellman as a hint.

I am not sure how to go about this, this is something I came up with:

Alice and Bob enact DH as normal. After Alice receives $g^b$ mod $p$ and Bob receives $g^a$ mod $p$ instead of just computing $g^{ab}$ mod $p$ as their shared key, they add *X* as well, for $g^{abX}$ mod $p$.

Since $p$ will be much larger than $X$ the whole key can't be brute forced easily. A MiM attack Trudy can try in normal DH is to establish $g^{at}$ mod $p$ with Alice and $g^{bt}$ mod $p$ with Bob. My understanding is $x$ or $g^{atx}$ mod or $g^{btx}$ mod $p$ would be expensive to find for Trudy, thus Alice and Bob retain confidentiality.

I'm not sure if I'm overthinking the problem or if what I came up with adds that much more security that couldn't be achieved in a simpler way. Is my method OK? What could a more secure system be?

Comment: could this be related to password based key exchange?

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is $x$ or $g^{atx} \bmod p$ or $g^{btx} \bmod p$ would be expensive to find for Trudy, thus Alice and Bob retain confidentiality.

Not really.  Trudy knows $g^a$ (Alice sent that) and $t$ (Trudy picked that); let us assume that Alice uses the value $g^{atx} \bmod p$ for something, such as deriving symmetric keys, and then uses that to encrypt a message.  What Trudy could do it compute $(g^a)^{tx} \bmod p$, for all possible values of $x$, and derive keys from all of them; that's 16384 possible keys.  Trudy can then try to decrypt Alice's message using each key; the one that works will tell her the correct value of $x$ (and then she can either continue with a MITM attack, or impersonate Bob).

There are protocols that don't have this weakness, examples include [EKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_key_exchange) and [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol); these don't prevent Trudy from taking a random guess of $x$, attempting a MITM attack (and learning whether that was the $x$ that Alice and Bob shared); what they do is make sure that Trudy can't do any better; to test 1000 possible $x$ values, she'll need to perform the MITM attack 1000 times.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, this method would work. And it will still be vulnerable to the MITM attack you mention without any authentication of the parties.

Answer (score 0):

After class it seems a good answer would be for Alice and Bob to to normal DH, except encrypt $g^{a}$ mod p and $g^{b}$ mod p with their shared 14-bit symmetric key. The DH MiM is a real time attack and Trudy has a limited window. Also, $g^{a}$ mod p and $g^{b}$ mod p are not plain messages, so Trudy would not know if she found the right key trying to brute force all 16k possibilities.